# Which unit of measurement is used in this Office Open XML Element

Tags: ms-office, openxml

The following element is a pic, it can be parsed by PowerPoint. I got confused with it's
measuring units  for a couple of hours.

English Metric units (EMUs), points, picas, and inches ?

**DPI=96**
      xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
      xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"

```
 <p:pic>
  ....
    <a:srcRect l="5556"/>

  <p:spPr bwMode="auto">
    <a:xfrm>
      <a:off x="3545" y="759"/>
      <a:ext cx="782" cy="150"/>
    </a:xfrm>
 .....
  </p:spPr>
</p:pic>
```

[image]

Comment: What part is confusing? Check [this](http://www.asknumbers.com/CentimetersToPointsConversion.aspx) conversion table.

Answer (score 0):

English Metric Units are used for measuring sizes and positions of Vector Drawing and Pictures. Everything you need w.r.t. to Measuring Units in Open XML can be found [here](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/).

Comment: Did you check the site in the link I've provided?

Comment: Yes, but it's not English Metric Units,

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough experience working with drawings and Pictures in Open XML, let me get back to you with an example.

Answer (score 0):

This involves more than a mere measure unit...

"DPI 96" comes from a VGA screen size of (or mode) 640x480... maybe other values you could find out there can be "DPI 72" for an EGA screen size of 640x350 or "DPI 48" for a CGA screen size of 640:200 ...

Those things came from the very beginning: MSDOS, Macintosh(Sw&Hw) and IBM PC. On those years (80's) there was several graphic modes each with their own pixel size that graphical drivers managed to draw on those very primitive monitors (very low resolutions and screen size, monochrome, no standars!). DPI 96 stands for "dot per inch 96x96", as VGA pixel is a square of 96x96. CGA and EGA have rectangular pixels of 48×96 and 72×96 respectively...

I'm sure that checking this URLs will help you...

[Where does 96 DPI come from in Windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fontblog/archive/2005/11/08/490490.aspx?Redirected=true)

[DPI & PPI explained](http://www.ransen.com/articles/dpi/default.htm)